# CSRF implementation in core CKAN code

Tags: fiware, ckan

[This](https://github.com/data-govt-nz/ckanext-security) extension to CKAN could work to provide security features in CKAN. This extension provides Cookie-based CSRF protection for requests in CKAN. But according to [this](https://github.com/ckan/ckan/pull/2359) , it is not implemented as a part of core CKAN because the method used in this extension to provide CSRF protection is conflicting with the future plan of CKAN's own implementation of CSRF protection.

So, my question is 
1. Is there any implementation of CSRF protection in core CKAN code? 
2. What are different methods we can use to implement CSRF protection and what is the best method to implement it in core CKAN?

Comment: Just so you're aware, the pull request you linked is obsolete; the Queensland Government CKAN extension no longer relies on patching that JavaScript file.

Answer (score 1):

1. Not at present time. It really needs someone to do it.
2. [The PR discussion you linked](https://github.com/ckan/ckan/pull/2359) contains several suggestions of how it should be done. I imagine it just needs a bit of work to pull it together. I suggest creating a new GitHub issue with the proposal, before doing a PR. It would benefit lots of projects.

The CKAN team and I are always pleased to see PRs in CKAN, and that PR author made a great effort to generalize his/her solution and put it forward as a PR. It's just a shame that the author and the CKAN team didn't find agreement on that one. It happens in open source. Shepherding a project means tough choices sometimes, and not always right. It usually helps though to discuss before implementing. Plenty of PRs do get merged, and then everyone benefits.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to (1) is sadly still, "No." However, there are a couple of options for (2):

- Applying the `SameSite` attribute to all relevant cookies (especially the `auth_tkt` cookie) should cover 90%+ of cases in browsers that support the attribute. This could be achieved with something like Apache's `mod_headers`.
- The discussion that you saw has since produced a stand-alone extension, https://github.com/qld-gov-au/ckanext-csrf-filter, which should provide effective CSRF protection on CKAN 2.8 and 2.9 (possibly 2.7, but I haven't specifically tested that).